# How to set null values if user does not supply any values in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

Hi guys i have a following code for entering data into database using C# Sql and ADO.NET.I have two columns for which i want that if user dont want to enter values in `ITEM_MODEL` and `QUANTITY` than it should save as null in database .I have allowed `IS NULL` for that column.When i am supplying empty values for these columns it saying `MUST DECLARE VALUES @ITEM_MODEL`.I want that these columns automatically take null values if user deosnt supply any values:

```
try
                {
                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString))
                    {
                        string query = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_CREDIT_RECORDS VALUES(@CUSTOMER_NAME,@TODAYS_TOTAL,@AMOUNT_RECIEVED,0,@DATE_SALE,@ITEM_MODEL,@QUANTITY,@CUSTOMER_CODE)";
                        da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@CUSTOMER_NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtCustomerName.Text;
                        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@TODAYS_TOTAL", SqlDbType.Money).Value = txtTodaystotal.Text;
                        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@AMOUNT_RECIEVED", SqlDbType.Money).Value = txtAmountRecieved.Text;
                        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DATE_SALE", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;

                        if (!String.Equals(txtTodaystotal.Text, "0"))
                        { 
                            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ITEM_MODEL", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtItemModelCredir.Text;
                            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@QUANTITY", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtQuantityCredit.Text;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ITEM_MODEL", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "";
                            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@QUANTITY", SqlDbType.Int).Value = "";
                        }

                        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@CUSTOMER_CODE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtCustomerCode.Text;

                        con.Open();
                        da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Customer does not exist", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                }
```

Comment: If you want to set them to null why are you using empty strings?

Comment: You can assign default value NULL to those fields *on db server* side. So when new record inserted, those fields will be assigned NULL, if there is no any explicit value specified in query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `DBNull.Value`. When you have no value to insert, you can use this value and then the corresponding record's column value will be null.

For instance, using your code:

```
if (!String.Equals(txtTodaystotal.Text, "0"))
{ 
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ITEM_MODEL", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtItemModelCredir.Text;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@QUANTITY", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtQuantityCredit.Text;
}
else
{
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ITEM_MODEL", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@QUANTITY", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use the field names when you `INSERT`.  This serves to:

1. Ensure any changes to the table will have minimal impact on your code.  If a DBA recreates the table with columns in a different order, or add columns (possibly with column defaults), your code won't break or do something horrible like insert data into the wrong columns.
2. You can exclude any columns you don't have data for from the field list entirely. This allows the database to choose the default, if set at a column level.  If you decide you want to insert a default `0` value for some metric when you don't have the value, you could just set that at the database level.

Example:

```
INSERT TABLE ( FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3 ) VALUES ( @FIELD1, @FIELD2, @FIELD3 );
```

If you don't have a value for @FIELD2, you can just generate:

```
INSERT TABLE ( FIELD1, FIELD3 ) VALUES ( @FIELD1, @FIELD3 );
```

Even if you don't plan to use this method to fix your missing data issue, it's still a good idea to list the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using Stored Procedure - which by the way would be more comfortable. In stored procedure you can define default values to parameters --> then you would just set them to be NULL or whatever you want.
In your case it's totally your responsibility - validating the input. Thus you can just check your input for null or empty and depends on that decision choose between passing the input or a DbNull value. Your code would look something like that:

```
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ITEM_MODEL", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtItemModelCredir.Text) ? DBNull.Value : txtItemModelCredir.Text;
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@QUANTITY", SqlDbType.Int).Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtQuantityCredit.Text) ? DBNull.Value : txtQuantityCredit.Text;
```